# problem in connecting django html templates

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

whenever i try to connect my template my browser shows following error

> > > TemplateDoesNotExist at /
> > >       test.html
> > >       Request Method:
> > >       GET
> > >       Request URL:
> > >       http://localhost:8000/
> > >       Django Version:
> > >       3.0.5
> > >       Exception Type:
> > >       TemplateDoesNotExist
> > >       Exception Value:
> > >       test.html
> > >       Exception Location:
> > >       C:\Users\NIKHIL MISHRA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py in get_template, line 19
> > >       Python Executable:
> > >       C:\Users\NIKHIL MISHRA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe
> > >       Python Version:
> > >       3.7.7
> > >       Python Path:
> > >       ['C:\pro\myproject',
> > >        'C:\Users\NIKHIL '
> > >        'MISHRA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip',
> > >        'C:\Users\NIKHIL MISHRA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs',
> > >        'C:\Users\NIKHIL MISHRA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib',
> > >        'C:\Users\NIKHIL MISHRA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37',
> > >        'C:\Users\NIKHIL '
> > >        'MISHRA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages']
> > >       Server time:
> > >       Mon, 4 May 2020 21:28:42 +0000

i have created templates folder and having test.html file in it
also my myapp\views.py (app name)file code looks like this

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request,'test.html')
```

and my myapp\urls.py is this

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from . import views

urlpatterns=[

    url(r'^$',views.index),


]
```

ps edit: my templates setting

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

edit 2:their was i typo in my directory name else the code is working fine
thnx ...

Comment: Please add your `TEMPLATES` setting

Comment: sure im adding it right now

Comment: Where is `test.html` and the folder that it is in? It needs to be in a directory named `templates` that's either in the root of your project or in one of your apps

Comment: Can you share an example of your folder structure

Comment: C:\pro\myproject